# Xcode 7 and openCV (no Swift): Core.hpp header must be compiled as C++

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode, opencv

I have followed the [instructions](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/ios/video_processing/video_processing.html#example-video-frame-processing-project) on how to install OpenCV on an iOS project. However when using Xcode 7 I had to add manually a prefix header. Doing this unfortunately did not help and I was still getting compile errors. I then read another post suggesting that is best to add manually the imports and not use prefix headers in Xcode 7, so I did.

Here is my code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <opencv2/highgui/cap_ios.h>
//using namespace cv;

@interface ViewController ()
{
    IBOutlet UIImageView* imageView;
    IBOutlet UIButton* button;
}

- (IBAction)actionStart:(id)sender;

@end
```

However I still get the following errors.

[image]
[image]

When I uncomment the using namespace cv; I get the following:

[image]

I found some complex solutions talking about exposing headers to Swift etc.. I just want my project to work on Objective-C with Xcode 7 ...

Comment: The code requires C++ features; you have to use objective C++, not objective C. The quickest 'workaround' is to rename your `.m` file to `.mm`; but this is kicking the fact that you're now writing `C++` down the road at that point.

Comment: I tried but it still won't work..

Comment: Did you get this to work? @mm24

Answer (score 31, accepted):

OpenCV is a `C++` framework, which means that any code that makes use of OpenCV has to be compiled with `C++` interpretation, rather than `C` interpretation.

The errors you see, e.g. with the `using namespace cv;` indicate that the code is compiled using the objective-C compiler, rather than the objective-C++ compiler.

As I mentioned in my comment the easiest way to get this to happen is to ensure that any file that `#include`s an opencv header must be named e.g. `ViewController.mm`, i.e. it must be an Objective-C++ file.

Alternatively, you can select and override the `Type` of the file, by explicitly selecting the `Objective-C++ Source` option for the file type in the utilities pane.
 [image: utilities pane drop-down selection]

Comment: thank you for the clear explanation. I will try this tomorrow and let you know how I got on.. cheers, and thanks a lot for replying  :)

Comment: @mm24 did you ever get around this problem? I'm facing same issue and none of the solutions seem to work. :/

Comment: I had to stop working on this and find an alternative solution. I tried but not enough to confirm whether it works or not. I accept as it has 4 up-votes and sounds sensible.

Comment: @mm24 I am also facing same error, already tried above things but it didn't work,

can you please help me what else you have tried.

I know it's a pretty old post but anything you remembered that can helps me a lot.

Answer (score 15):

I just had the exact same problem. I'm working in a Swift project with OpenCV.

Regarding Swift, its entry point to OpenCV is a file I called OpenCVWrapper. So I got OpenCVWrapper.h and OpenCVWrapper.mm. In the bridging header of my project, I got #import "OpenCVWrapper.h".

Thing is I wanted to write a class called MatUtils in Objective-C++ that I could call from OpenCVWrapper.mm. For them to be seeable in there, I had to put them in MatUtils.h.

Long story short, the mistake is that in OpenCVWrapper.h, I did #import "MatUtils.h". MISTAKE!!!! As OpenCVWrapper is in the bridging header, C++ is now reachable from Swift!

Quick fix : #import "MatUtils.h" in OpenCVWrapper.mm!

Cheers!
bRo

Comment: Just ran into a similar issue. After a few minutes I realized that I could re-open the interface in the .mm and place the instance properties inside that, rather than the main wrapper.h which otherwise had put me into a recursion :-)

Comment: Yes! I think you were following this https://medium.com/compileswift/ios-opencv-and-swift-1ee3e3a5735b which wasn't real clear about that, thanks.

Comment: Hello, indeed I was following that article, because I'm the one that wrote it haha.
I have to update that article, some things are out of date :)

Comment: @bRo, did you end up updating? I am having the same problem but I followed the same steps as your article and the other ones.

Comment: Not yet, I'll find time soon, I promise :)

Comment: Thank you so much.. that did help me

Answer (score 3):

The solution is almost the same as we do bridging ObjectiveC and swift but we do it between Objective C and C++ so we put the C++ codes in a separate file with (.mm) extension and then import it to your Objective C File (.m)

For example if you have ViewController.h and ViewController.m you add two more files which include your C++ codes lets name it OpenCV.mm and OpenCV.h then import the OpenCV.h inside ViewController.m even before you import anything else.
May be this image will help understand it:
[image]

Tested on Xcode 11.6 OpenCV Ver 3.4.3

Comment: Thank you. This image really helps to clear things up.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing `#import < opencv2/opencv.hpp >` before `#import "ViewController.h"`.[Source](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/6114#issuecomment-184721408)